# Ansible URI module - OneView API query error: URL can't contain control character - (found at least ' ')

Tags: module, ansible, uri

I am using the URI module to return all the active alerts from a HPE OneView appliance

```yaml
- name: connect to OneView and get alerts
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    #url: https://{{ oneview_appliance }}/rest/alerts?view=alertSummary&filter="alertState EQ 'Active'"
    method: GET
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      X-Api-Version: 4000
      auth: "{{ ov_session_id }}"
    validate_certs: false
  register: oneview_active_alerts
```

The above errors with:

```
 "url": "https://10.0.0.1/rest/alerts?view=alertSummary&filter=\"alertState EQ 'Active'\"",
    "status": -1,
    "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: An unknown error occurred: URL can't contain control characters. '/rest/alerts?view=alertSummary&filter=\"alertState EQ \\'Active\\'\"' (found at least ' ')",
```

If I truncate the URL so there are no quotes passed to the query, the API call works (but obviously doesn't return the required results)
url: https://{{ oneview_appliance }}/rest/alerts?view=alertSummary&filter=

Is it possible to parse the full query including the required quotes, in to the URI module?

Comment: The problem is not quotes but spaces (as reported by your error message => `(found at least ' ')`. You need to urlencode them. Ansible has a [filter for that](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#urlencode-variables)

Comment: I've tried to urlencode the query, the URI module accepts the encoded query but the API ignores it.  I'll see if I can manually encode the spaces

Comment: Yep, changing

"alertState EQ 'Active'"

to 

"alertState%20EQ%20Active'"

does work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with our network setup, the IP address was not being treated as such and was being routed incorrectly.

Changing to the FQDN of the endpoint allowed our network to route the request to the correct location and it started working